# Magento 2: What's the `page_layout` folder for?

Tags: magento2, xml, page-layouts, view

In addition to containing familiar folders like `layout`, and `templates`, a Magento 2 module's `view` folder also contains a `page_layout` sub-folder.

```
view/adminhtml/page_layout
view/frontend/page_layout
```

What is this folder for?  How would I, as a Magento module developer, use this folder?  Or is this something reserved for core Magento modules that has no functionality exposed for third party developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2 split page layouts on 2 components:

1. page layouts - define page structure (support only containers)
2. general layouts - add blocks to container

See [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html) for more details